# transformation: normal distributed variables -> uniform distributed variables

Tags: statistics

suppose I have a vector `x` of normal distributed variables with mean `m` and standard diviation `s`.

Is there an efficient (explicit) function `f(x, m, s)` transforming `x` to uniform distributed vector?

With **explicit** I mean that the function only utilizes standard mathematical operations like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `pow()`, `exp()` but no for loops. So actually I'm looking for a transformation function approximating the cumulative distribution function of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: is it suppose to read 'a vector x of normal distributed variables...'?

Comment: yes, the vector x should contain normal distributed variables

Comment: however I think I found a good solution. I posted it below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in this [paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2012/124029/) I found a suolution for a uniform distribution with mean=0 and std=1. To make it applicable to any mean and std one has to substract the mean `m` and divide by the std `s`:

```
x = (x - m) / s
x_uni = 1. / (exp(-(358. * x)/23. + 111. * arctan(37. * x / 294.)) + 1)
```